# Removing button's bottom border except the last 3 buttons in the button list using pure javascript if not other options is fine

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got 3 sets of buttons, each set contains 9 buttons stack in 3 columns placed inside < ol >< li > 9 buttons here < /li >< /ol >. I already remove button's bottom border to avoid double border because they are stacked on top of each other without any gap (margin, padding). What I'm trying to achieve is to retain bottom border of the last 3 buttons.

Here's my initial code: (not working)

```
    var lo = document.querySelectorAll('ol');
    for (var h = 0; h < lo.length; h++) {
        var li = lo[h].querySelectorAll('li');
        for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
            var p = li[i].querySelectorAll('button');
            for (var j = 0; j < button.length; j++) {
                if (i > (button.length-3)) {
                    document.getElementsByTagName("button").style.borderBottom = '2px solid red';
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: why don't you remove the border of the last 3 buttons with css?

Comment: I already did. I said retain not remove.

Comment: You should be seeing an error in your browser's dev tools console at document.getElementsByTagName("button").style.borderBottom = '2px solid red'; You are getting a collection of all the button elements rather than the button you are interested in.

Comment: Actually you should be seeing other errors too, button is undefined, I think you mean p. If you sort out these errors then the code's logic is OK and it should work.

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function removeBottomBorderExceptLast3() {
            var collectionOfLists = document.getElementsByTagName("ol");   

            for(var i = 0; i < collectionOfLists.length; i++) {
                var myList = collectionOfLists[i].getElementsByTagName("li");

                for(var j = 0; j < myList.length - 3; j++) {
                    var listItem = myList[j];
                    listItem.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].style.borderBottom = "none";
                }
            }    


        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ol id="myList1">
        <li><button>1</button></li>
        <li><button>2</button></li>
        <li><button>3</button></li>
        <li><button>4</button></li>
        <li><button>5</button></li>
        <li><button>6</button></li>
        <li><button>7</button></li>
        <li><button>8</button></li>
        <li><button>9</button></li>
    </ol>

    <ol id="myList2">
        <li><button>10</button></li>
        <li><button>11</button></li>
        <li><button>12</button></li>
        <li><button>13</button></li>
        <li><button>14</button></li>
        <li><button>15</button></li>
        <li><button>16</button></li>
        <li><button>17</button></li>
        <li><button>18</button></li>
    </ol>

    <ol id="myList3">
        <li><button>19</button></li>
        <li><button>20</button></li>
        <li><button>21</button></li>
        <li><button>22</button></li>
        <li><button>23</button></li>
        <li><button>24</button></li>
        <li><button>25</button></li>
        <li><button>26</button></li>
        <li><button>27</button></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- <button onclick="removeBottomBorderExceptLast3();">Remove</button> -->

    <script>
        removeBottomBorderExceptLast3();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time implementing this using `<body onload="">`. It only works for the first set of `<ol></ol>`.

Comment: any suggestion implementing this using one function with multiple `<ol></ol>`

Comment: updated the code. i think it is more accurate to call the removeBottomBorderExceptLast3 function after the dom is build rather than <body onload=".

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors in the code which result in it not working.

I have renamed some of the variables to make it easier to see what we are dealing with at any time. You need to check that I have the conditional statements right as I'm not absolutely sure which buttons you are wanting to underline.

```
//get all the ol elements into allOls
var allOls = document.querySelectorAll('ol');
for (var h = 0; h < allOls.length; h++) {

    // get all the li elements within a particular ol into lis
    var lis = allOls[h].querySelectorAll('li');
    for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {

        //get all the button elements within this particular li into buttons
        var buttons = lis[i].querySelectorAll('button');
        for (var j = 0; j < buttons.length; j++) {
            if (j > (buttons.length-3)) {//IS THIS THE RIGHT CONDITION?
                buttons[j].style.borderBottom = '2px solid red';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I'm trying to do. I've tested the code but for some reasons I can't explain it is adding bottom border to all the buttons inside `< li > < /li >`.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work using @Umit Can Cukadar solution but I think the logic inside the function is redundant. I'm open if someone can simplify or make it shorter.

My Solution:
**SCRIPT**

```
        function removeBottomBorderExceptLast3(listName, listName2, listName3) {
        var myOl = document.getElementById(listName).getElementsByTagName("ol");
        for(var i = 0; i < myOl.length; i++) {

            var myLi = document.getElementById(listName).getElementsByTagName("li");
            for(var j = 0; j < myLi.length - 3; j++) {
                var listItem = myLi[j];
                listItem.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].style.borderBottom = "none";
            }
        }
        var myOl2 = document.getElementById(listName2).getElementsByTagName("ol");
        for(var i = 0; i < myOl2.length; i++) {

            var myLi = document.getElementById(listName2).getElementsByTagName("li");
            for(var j = 0; j < myLi.length - 3; j++) {
                var listItem = myLi[j];
                listItem.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].style.borderBottom = "none";
            }
        }
        var myOl3 = document.getElementById(listName3).getElementsByTagName("ol");
        for(var i = 0; i < myOl3.length; i++) {

            var myLi = document.getElementById(listName3).getElementsByTagName("li");
            for(var j = 0; j < myLi.length - 3; j++) {
                var listItem = myLi[j];
                listItem.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].style.borderBottom = "none";
            }
        }
    }
```

**BODY**

```
<body onload="removeBottomBorderExceptLast3('myList', 'myList2', 'myList3');">
<div id="myList">
    <ol style="list-style-type:none">
        <li><div class="btn"><button>THIS IS BUTTON 1</button></div></li>
        <li><div class="btn"><button>THIS IS BUTTON 2</button></div></li>
        <li><div class="btn"><button>THIS IS BUTTON 3</button></div></li>
        <li><div class="btn"><button>THIS IS BUTTON 4</button></div></li>
        <li><div class="btn"><button>THIS IS BUTTON 5</button></div></li>
        <li><div class="btn"><button>THIS IS BUTTON 6</button></div></li>
        <li><div class="btn"><button>THIS IS BUTTON 7</button></div></li>
        <li><div class="btn"><button>THIS IS BUTTON 8</button></div></li>
        <li><div class="btn"><button>THIS IS BUTTON 9</button></div></li>
    </ol>
</div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <div id="myList2"> 
    <ol style="list-style-type:none">
        <li><div class="btn"><button>THIS IS BUTTON 1</button></div></li>
        <li><div class="btn"><button>THIS IS BUTTON 2</button></div></li>
        <li><div class="btn"><button>THIS IS BUTTON 3</button></div></li>
        <li><div class="btn"><button>THIS IS BUTTON 4</button></div></li>
        <li><div class="btn"><button>THIS IS BUTTON 5</button></div></li>
        <li><div class="btn"><button>THIS IS BUTTON 6</button></div></li>
        <li><div class="btn"><button>THIS IS BUTTON 7</button></div></li>
        <li><div class="btn"><button>THIS IS BUTTON 8</button></div></li>
        <li><div class="btn"><button>THIS IS BUTTON 9</button></div></li>
    </ol>
</div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <div id="myList3"> 
    <ol style="list-style-type:none">
        <li><div class="btn"><button>THIS IS BUTTON 1</button></div></li>
        <li><div class="btn"><button>THIS IS BUTTON 2</button></div></li>
        <li><div class="btn"><button>THIS IS BUTTON 3</button></div></li>
        <li><div class="btn"><button>THIS IS BUTTON 4</button></div></li>
        <li><div class="btn"><button>THIS IS BUTTON 5</button></div></li>
        <li><div class="btn"><button>THIS IS BUTTON 6</button></div></li>
        <li><div class="btn"><button>THIS IS BUTTON 7</button></div></li>
        <li><div class="btn"><button>THIS IS BUTTON 8</button></div></li>
        <li><div class="btn"><button>THIS IS BUTTON 9</button></div></li>
    </ol>
</div>
```